# Jquery load function that will append onto HTML already present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX call which will append html i.e. add additional html to what is already present between the tags. Here is what my load function looks like.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".tid-select").change(function(){
        $(".tid-list").load("/saffron_main/test");
      });
    });
</script>
```

How would I modify this function in order to get it to append to the class .tid-list. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to append instead of replace?

Comment: Exactly, I want to append instead of replace

Comment: You can't use `load()` then I think - you'll have to do a normal .ajax() call http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ and then append in the success callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or instead of replacing the html you can just load the data into a variable and then add it to the DOM.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/saffron_main/test',
    success: function (data) {
        $('.tid-list').append(data);
    }
});
```

This way events that have been bound to the existing html will stay bound.

Answer (score 4):

You have to get data via ajax and use `$('.tid-list').append(data);`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tid-select").change(function(){
   $.get("/saffron_main/test",function(data){
    $('.tid-list').append(data);
   });
 });
});
</script>
```

You may also use `$('.tid-list').prepend(data);` to insert before the current HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the change handler

```
$(".tid-select").change(function(){
   $.get("/saffron_main/test", function(data){
      $(".tid-list").append(data);
   });
});
```

edit: yeah, the other guys are right that append makes more sense